# Marginal Treatment Effects using MTEFE - postestimation discrepancy

Tags: stata, propensity-scores, treatment-effect, marginal-effect, heterogeneity

I am currently calculating [Marginal Treatment Effects](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1801800108) for an outcome Y (earnings) and a treatment D (joining sector 1 vs sector 0), using the MTEFE package from Stata.
I use a separate approach with a polynomial 1 and find a downward sloping curve and based on the results, the ATE is -0.63, the ATT is -0.48 and the ATUT is -0.7 (consistent with the downward sloping curve).

I then want to do a postestimation and calculate the expected treatment effects for every individual in my sample with characteristics X, D, and p. I follow the formula in p. 137. If I sum this for my sample, I find a similar value as the previous ATE. However, if I sum over individuals for whom D=1, I find a value of -1 and if I sum over individuals who whom D=0, I find a value of -0.6, which does not align with the previous ATT and ATUT (I should find that summing over individuals with D=1 give me a less negative value than when I sum for individuals for whom D=0). I find similar patterns when using the LIV method.

It seems to me that my formula to calculate for the postestimation is right so I am wondering whether my finding makes any sense or whether it clearly shows I am making a mistake somewhere. My Y is earnings and my D is an indicator for joining the private sector (vs Academia - I am looking at PhD). Could it be that because there is capacity constraint in either one sector, the postestimated effect go in the other direction? I have trouble reconciling the pre- vs post-estimation estimates.